# Nuxt 3 + Vite & HMR : infinite reload & failed

Tags: vue.js, vite

On a fresh install of Nuxt3, using Docker, I have this error on the console and an infinite reload of the page :

> client.ts:28 WebSocket connection to 'wss://shop.store.local/_nuxt/'
> failed:  (anonyme) @ client:188 client.ts:224 [vite] server connection
> lost. polling for restart...

Here is the configuration of my vite server (via `nuxt.config.js`):

```
 vite: {
    server: {
      hmr: {
        host: 'shop.store.local',
        port: 443,
      }
    }
  }
```

The docker-compose describes the Traefik labels:

```
  vuejs:
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.front_store.rule=Host(`shop.store.local`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.front_store.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.services.front_store.loadbalancer.server.port=3000"
```

What I've tried too, in my `package.json` file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxi dev --host=0.0.0.0",
    "build": "nuxi build",
    "start": "node .output/server/index.mjs"
  },
```

Any idea ? I looked over internet, people have the problem, but no solution...

Comment: I have the same problem. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Try to make working this several time and spend a lot of time for it. I believe something is wrong with websocket with Traefik, apparently it can work without doing something but in really it is not very true.. Continue to investigate but if someone finds the solution one day, do not hesitate to share please :)

Answer (score 2):

Expose ports for nuxt container.

ports:

- 3000:3000
- 24678:24678

Also edit your nuxt.config:

```
vite: {
    server: {
      host: "0.0.0.0",
      hmr: {

      },
    },
  },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Adding the "24678:24678" Ports to the docker-compose file solved it for me. thanks!