# Vite - Websocket connection lost in production

Tags: node.js, vite

currently struggling with a error message when accessing my website.
Everything else seems to work fine! I think the error is related to vite hmr (which is working fine with dev:client).

I run the application in a docker container, when starting with "dev:server" or "serve" I get the error

```
    "dev:server": "npx nodemon",
    "dev:client": "npm run build:client && vite --config vite.config.ts dev --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "rimraf dist && tsc -p tsconfig.json && npm run build:client && npm run build:server && npm run copy-files",
    "build:client": "vite build --outDir dist/client --ssrManifest",
    "build:server": "vite build --ssr src/client/entryServer.tsx --outDir dist/server",
    "serve": "npm run build && cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./dist/server/",
    "copy-files": "copyfiles \"public/**/*\" dist && copyfiles -u 2 \"dist/client/**/*\" dist && copyfiles -u 2 \"dist/client/assets/**/*\" dist/public",
```

here is the error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://example:24678/' failed: 
[vite] server connection lost. polling for restart...
GET http://example:24678/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
GET http://example:24678/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT    
GET http://example:24678/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
...
```

thats just looping all the time...

here is my vite config

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
const PORT = process.env.VITE_PORT ? parseInt(process.env.VITE_PORT) : 3000;

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    port: PORT,
    watch: {
      usePolling: true,
    },
  },
  build: {
    minify: false,
  },
  // improt environment variables from .env files to the client
  define: {
    "import.meta.env": JSON.stringify(process.env),
  },
});
```

UPDATE:

locally I got rid of the error by exposing port 24678 in docker-compose
just as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73783969/20480920)
But on the server I still have the same problem even with the exposed port on my docker container...
I tried adding a firewall rule to allowing traffic on that port.

```
sudo ufw allow 24678
```

But it's still showing the error.

UPDATE-2:

I also tried whats described [here](https://dev.to/yaroslaff/svelte-kit-with-hmr-over-nginx-2pl2) and added port 24678 to server block in my vite.config

```
hmr: {
  clientPort: 3000,
},
```

and then I added another nginx server for the websocket connection to my nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 24678 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate     /path/to/ssl/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/ssl/private_key.key;   

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://container-name:24678/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Still not working.

UPDATE:

I also tried setting up the nginx reverse proxy with

```
location /websocket {
...
}
```